# Convert factor to a string using a template string in R

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe with values like

```
d = data.frame(value = runif(1000, 10,50))
```

and the values are classified into groups using `cut`

```
d$class = cut(d$value, 4)
```

how can quickly convert the `factor` objects to strings representing the range? For example:

```
(10,20] -> "10 to 20"
```

I tried making a function, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way.

```
style.factor <- function(factors, template="%s to %s") {
  parts = str_split(str_sub(factors, 2, -2), ",", simplify=TRUE)
  return(sprintf(template, parts[,1], parts[,2]))
}
```

```
> style.factor(d$class)
  "40 to 50" "20 to 30" "30 to 40" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` to do this relatively quickly:

```r
gsub("^\\((.+?),(.+?)\\]$", "\\1 to \\2", d$class)
```

Comment: This can be done "quickly" only for small dataset. For large datasets, It's better to modify factor levels directly.

Answer (score 2):

Using an approach similar to yours but with the `levels` function.

```
 # extract levels
 levels_c <- levels(d$class)

 # form and assign new levels
 library(stringr)
 parts = str_split(str_sub(levels_c , 2, -2), ",", simplify=TRUE)
 template="%s to %s"
 levels(d$class) <- sprintf(template, parts[,1], parts[,2])

 # check the outcome
 levels(d$class)
 # [1] "10 to 20" "20 to 30" "30 to 40" "40 to 50"
```

Naturally, if you wish to convert to characters

```
d$class <- as.character(d$class)
```

Comment: This is actually a better approach because it preserves the numerical order of the groups when graphing (e.g. so "9 to 11" doesn't appear before "11 to 13")